# Adding in-app prices to my app

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to add in-app purchases to my app, so before the user clicks the purchase button they can see the price. I want to do this programmatically since every country has a different currency. Is this possible to do? I can't seem to find anything online or I'm using the wrong keywords to look this up.

Comment: check this out: https://stripe.com/

Comment: There's no way to do this without using something like stripe? I can't use Googles API no?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for in-app Billing has a small tutorial for querying prices](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryDetails). It states

> To retrieve this information from Google Play, call the `getSkuDetails` method on the In-app Billing API

The [API documentation for `getSkuDetails()`](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html#getSkuDetails) states this about the JSON response’s `price` key:

> Formatted price of the item, including its currency sign. The price does not include tax.

So if you just query the app store using this API, you can get the information you need.

You have not told us what you have, what frameworks you’re using, or what your code so far looks like, so we cannot help you with getting from where you are to calling the `getSkuDetails()` method. But we can say: there is an API and documentation for exactly that ;-).

Comment: Yeah I had found that recently today, I had the whole time I was just missing one small thing from the whole thing, thanks!